# Can't access many websites through wired connection

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, wired

On my laptop I can't access a lot of websites, other websites can be accessed but no images. As an example google.com doesn't work but I can use bing.com. This is only an issue on wired connection, there is no issues with WIFI.

Also I can ping all websites and have no package loss.

The computer is an HP 755 G2, with windows 8.1, no antivirus.

What I've tryed:

- Using different cables
- Testing cables on other computers (works fine just not on mine)
- Testing on other networks
- Testing on multiple different browsers
- Testing with different DNS providers (8.8.8.8 - 8.8.4.4)
- ipconfig /flushdns from CMD
- ipconfig /renew from CMD
- Update all drivers (including network)
- Remove wired network drivers and reinstall
- Test without firewall enabled
- Test with WIFI off and Cable enabled
- Run in safe mode with only network options
- Change adapter speed and duplex
- Ping with large packets

Any help is appreciated, I've reached the point where I believe the cable modem is broken on the laptop.

Comment: Maybe, your problem can be found only with bigger packet size. Try to ping that websites with big packets. For example: ping example.com -t -l 1024 . Also you can try to change the connection speed in your network adapter settings from "Auto" to 100 or even 10 Mbps with half duplex mode and then try again to access that sites.

Comment: @JtHermit No issues pinging google with the example. Also settings adapter to 100 or 10 mbps with half duplex did nothing eighter.

Comment: There are some more tests that you can try: 1. New browser, that you did not use before. 2. Connect to site with any telnet-like program, such as putty (connection type: telnet; server: google.com; port: 80). 3. Boot with Linux live-cd/dvd/usb. 4. You wrote that your laptop has no antivirus. It may be good idea to scan and clean it with "adwcleaner" and then do a little system restoration with"AVZ" utility. Download and run it with command line "avz Lang=EN". Then go to File->System Restore, select entries 2, 4, 9, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23 and press "Execute selected operations".

Comment: Does the eventviewer show any related errors/warnings?

Comment: @doenoe it doesn't give any new errors when disconnecting wifi, connecting cable and trying to access a website.

There is some errors that might be related, do you want details of any of these?: WLAN-AutoConfig, DistributedCOM, CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment, CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a driver issue, even though hp support assistant and windows said drivers were up to date. Updated to new drivers found on hp website and everything works as it should...